# Convert space seperated string to class in php

Tags: php, regex, string

I have a string `'abc back'`

Is there a simple way to convert this to like this `"AbcBack"` in PHP

Comment: Use ucwords (http://php.net/manual/en/function.ucwords.php) then split on blank space or with str_replace destroy blank space... Why use a regex when not needed? -.-

Comment: I was expecting some sort of helper in php inbuild. I knew the ucwords(), however I wanted to see the best option.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Just try with [`ucwords`](http://php.net/ucwords):

```
$input  = 'abc back';
$output = str_replace(' ', '', ucwords($input));
```

Answer (score 2):

Use `ucfirst()` function in php.Use the code below

```
 <?php
    $string='abc back';
$p = explode($string," ");
$text="";
foreach($p as $m){
    $text .= ucfirst($m); 
}
echo str_replace(" ","",$text);// will print AbcBack
```

You can use `ucwords()` to. Use the code below

```
<?php
        $string='abc back';
echo str_replace(" ","",ucwords($string));
```

Hope this helps you

Comment: ucfirst works on first word, use ucwords for uppercase each word first letter

Comment: @Marco Mura Updated my answer have a look at it again

Comment: after your edit i've removed my downvote, is a way to do it. But won't it be better to use ucwords? That said, as a valid option i've upvoted you now

Comment: @Marco Mura Updated my answer again